# How to partially match a JSON key in Karate

Tags: karate

I have a response that looks this

```
{
  "metadata": {
     "Customer_x0020_Folder": "Test"
   }
}
```

I would like the assert key `Customer_x0020_Folder` is equal to 'Test'. However I don't care about the `x0020` portion of they key and would like to ignore that part. I would like to do something like:

```
match response contains { metadata: {'Customer_' + '#ignore' + '_Folder': 'Test'} }
```

How can I perform this assertion in Karate?

Answer (score 0):

Use `karate.keysOf()`:

```
* def response = { "metadata": { "Customer_x0020_Folder": "Test" } }
* def keys = karate.keysOf(response.metadata)
* match keys[0] == '#regex Customer_.*_Folder'
```